# javascript control over http statuses in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I was looking at [this wonderful website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) that tells you how to replace some useful jquery function with pure javascript and while I was looking at the AJAX request function I saw something a little bit strange to me... this line:

```
if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
```

It obviously works but I don't understand why they use this kind of control and not the usual one:

```
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
```

What's the difference between these two? Which is better and why?
I mean, when should make sense accept statuses from 200 to 399??

Comment: The first `if` statement will be `true` if the server responds with status codes between 200 and 399, the second (I think you mean status, not state) is specific to status code 200. http://httpstatus.es/ There is no better, just do what makes sense.

Comment: @azium yes sorry it was status. Anyway your explanation could be ok for those who are beginners... that's way too simple, I mean I knew that he was checking if the status was between 200 and 399 and I have already checked on wikipedia for those http statuses but I don't understand when should make sense accept statuses from 200 and 399.

Comment: Frankly I don't think it ever makes sense to write like that. It's far too general. In essence it's along the lines of "if the server response is not an error", but I would discourage writing code this ambiguously. Do you know what code 286 is? No? Neither do I. Be explicit.

Comment: So as I thought, thank you. Anyway you shouldn't write answers in the comment, you know?

Comment: Well I felt like it was a comment. This is just my opinion, not an "answer"

Comment: I noticed this the other day and used the latter also when comparing string values, couldn't understand it either.